# How to change the email that SES sends from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

Right now I have a few domains verified in AWS. I just started using SES with SMTP to send some emails from contact forms/password resets on my site but have run into a bit of an issue.

I have the domain `example.com` verified and am wanting to send emails from `no-reply@example.com` but whenever I send them it sends from my work email `me@example.com`

What can I do to get this setup? I posted on Reddit and was told that I can setup CloudFormation in order to do it but that seems way over complicated for what I'm trying to do. I just want to change the email that it's sent from on a verified domain, I would assume that's pretty simple.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used SES with the SMTP interface (from a .net application), and because my domains are verified, all I need to do is change the 'FROM' address, and it will send from whichever email address I want.

Here is a code example:

```
            using (var msg = new MailMessage())
            {
                msg.From = new MailAddress("anything@my-verified-domain.com");
                msg.To.Add(s.EmailAddress);
                msg.Subject = "Test Subject";
                msg.Body = body;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                msg.Headers.Add("X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET", "configset-1");
                using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtp.Send(msg);
                }
            }
```

Maybe if you shared some code we could see where you are going wrong.

Comment: That's odd, I just tried it again and now it seems to be sending properly. I was in sandbox mode last night when I first attempted it so maybe that's the reason why.